# NOT EXISTS invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like the following columns: bad_mrn, good_mrn, cr_date

```
insert into mrn_merge values ( '00000001','00000002', '20121120');
insert into mrn_merge values ( '00000002','00000003', '20121120');
insert into mrn_merge values ( '00000003','00000004', '20121120');
```

So in the end.
- 1 merged to 2
- 2 merged to 3 
- 3 merged to 4

I need a query that will return 4, if I provide an input parameter of 1, 2, 3, or 4.. 
The following prepared statement does work, but takes way to long when my mrn_merge table starts to have 40k records.

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT good_mrn, LEVEL
    FROM mrn_merge
    WHERE 
        (CONNECT_BY_ROOT bad_mrn =
            (SELECT bad_mrn FROM mrn_merge WHERE LEVEL =
                (SELECT MAX (LEVEL) FROM mrn_merge  START WITH good_mrn = ?
                 CONNECT BY PRIOR bad_mrn = good_mrn )
             START WITH good_mrn = ?
             CONNECT BY PRIOR bad_mrn = good_mrn)
        )  OR ( CONNECT_BY_ROOT bad_mrn = ?)
    START WITH  bad_mrn NOT IN ( SELECT good_mrn FROM mrn_merge  )
    CONNECT BY bad_mrn = PRIOR good_mrn  ORDER BY LEVEL DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ;
```

sql tuning advisor says to use "NOT EXISTS" in place of "NOT IN" but I get ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"..

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: did you think about Recursive functions yet ?http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Stored-Procedure-Function/Recursivefunction.htm

Comment: If you are running on a reasonably decent Oracle (>= 10g), you could investigate the `MODEL` clause http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/sqlmodel.htm#BEIDFCBH

Comment: What is the order of the columns in your sample INSERT? bad_mrn, good_mrn or good_mrn, bad_mrn? (It's a very bad habit to **not** specify the columns in the insert statement)

Comment: I did a recursive method in java, but I wanted to change that to have the database do the work for me. I know nothing about pl/sql, I need to get working on developing that skill..

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply swap `NOT IN` for `NOT EXISTS`.

`NOT IN` tests a column (or set of columns enclosed in parenthesis) against the result of a subquery, which must return the same number of columns.

```
SELECT a.cols
FROM table_a a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
  SELECT b.id
  FROM table_b b
)
```

or

```
SELECT a.cols
FROM table_a a
WHERE (a.id, a.name) NOT IN (
  SELECT b.id, b.name
  FROM table_b b
)
```

`NOT EXISTS` tests whether a subquery returns zero rows (TRUE) or one or more rows (FALSE). Normally, the subquery is *correlated* to the outer query, i.e. a column (or set of columns) inside the subquery is tested against a column (or set of columns) in the outer query.

```
SELECT a.cols
FROM table_a a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table_b b
  WHERE b.id = a.id
)
```

In your specific example, it doesn't seem to me like you can reasonably rewrite the clause to use `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody looked at this thanks.. But, my DBA was able to squeeze me in to help with this query.. The answer was to make it simpler and more efficient..

> select  good_mrn from ( select good_mrn, CONNECT_BY_ROOT bad_mrn, cr_date, bad_mrn 
>     from mrn_merge  Start with good_mrn= ? or bad_mrn=? 
>     connect by bad_mrn = prior good_mrn) where good_mrn not in 
>    (select bad_mrn from mrn_merge ) and rownum <=1;

Now it runs very efficiently. Thanks..